# String enum in Java

Tags: java, enums

I have an enum:

```
public enum ListEnums {
    TEST("test1"),
    TEST2("test2");
    private final String txt;
    ListEnums(String str){
        txt = str;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString(){return txt;}
```

I want get the enum string without call .toString().

Like:`mymethod(ListEnums.TEST);`

No: `mymethod(ListEnums.TEST.toString());`

Is it possible?

**EDIT**
The string return must be contains special chars.

Comment: Short answer: **no**. First, you have a typo on `"test2`. Next, you could give `txt` a different accessor (the primary reason it isn't possible, is that you can't sub-class `java.lang.String`).

Answer (score 1):

here:

```
public enum ListEnums {
    TEST("test1"),
    TEST2("test2);
    private final String txt;
    ListEnums(String str){
        txt = str;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return txt;
    }
```

if you call `ListEnum.TEST.name()` you will get TEST which is almost the same as calling **toString()**... if you instead do ListEnum.TEST then the name will be printed...

so Renaming the Enum constants is the way to go...

and the  best part is: you will get rid off the **constructor**, the **toString** method and the variable **txt**...

you just dont need it anymore. :)

Comment: What you changed? The problem is call something after ListEnums.TEST. If i will insert .name() or .toString() nothing changes.

Comment: @AlessioDP some how you are right but missing the point of my answer... i took your suggestion and update the answer... tnxs...

Comment: Thanks but i cannot use this way. The string returned need to be a complex string. I suppose is impossible what i want to do. (For a complex string a mean something like: "test.*123*.test"

Comment: The values is a configuration setting. It can be something like "test.base", "test.base2". (Must be contains dots and can contains numbers)

Answer (score 0):

It's OK, and a good practice to use getters in your enums.  Also good to keep your constructor private (though enums are private by default)....

```
public enum ListEnums {
    TEST("test1"),
    TEST2("test2");

    private final String txt;

    private ListEnums(String str){
        txt = str;
    }

    public String getTxt() {
        return txt;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(ListEnums.TEST.getTxt());
}
```

Comment: The same way to use toString method. I want remove that .getTxt().

Comment: That's how it's done.  Why do you need to remove the getter?

Comment: You can use toString() if you want, but that doesn't really scale well if you want to add more properties to your enum later.  So you should use getters.

Comment: @BradleyD Why won't it scale well?